# how to get records from database based on date range in asp.net linq

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I have develop a small web application in that i'm using entity frame work .i want get the records based on the date range and bind that data in gridview how can i write a query using linq..please help me..Here i have post my code what i have try to get records please .....

```
       var query = from p in entity.Payments
                    join D in entity.Debit_Method on p.Debit_Method_ID equals D.Debit_Method_ID
                    join pt in entity.Payment_Type on p.Payment_Type_ID equals pt.Payment_Type_ID
                    where p.Client_Pmt_Date >='1998-12-01' && p.Client_Pmt_Date<='1999-08-01' && p.Loan_ID=loanid
                    select new
                    {
                        p.Pmt_ID,
                        p.Loan_ID,
                        p.Client_Pmt_Date,
                        p.MtgSvr_Pmt_Start_Date2,
                        D.Debit_Method_Desc,
                        p.Total_Debit_Amt,
                        p.CreditAmt,
                        p.LenderAmt,
                        pt.Payment_Type_Desc,
                        p.Return_Code,
                        p.Returned_Date
                        //p.Pmt_ID,
                        // D.Debit_Method_Desc,
                        // pt.Payment_Type_Desc,
                        // p.Client_Pmt_Date,
                        // p.MtgSvr_Pmt_Start_Date2,
                        // p.Amt,
                        // p.CreditAmt,
                        // p.Loan_ID,
                        // p.Pmt_Comments

                        // p.Loan_ID,
                    };
        grdPayments.DataSource = query.ToList();
        grdPayments.DataBind();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to compare the Date to a DateTime object rather than a string. Here is a LINQ example with POCO (Plain Old CLR Objects):

```
var dates = new List<DateTime> { new DateTime(2011, 1, 1), new DateTime(2010, 1, 1), new DateTime(2009, 1, 1) };
var result1 = from x in dates where x < new DateTime(2011, 1, 1) && x > new DateTime(2009,1,1) select x;
var result2 = dates.Where(x => x < new DateTime(2011, 1, 1) && x > new DateTime(2009,1,1));
```

Comment: Hi thank you for giving responce..i want get the records using joins so,how can i write query ?can u please help me.

Comment: You will need to replace the >='1998-12-01' with >= new DateTime(1998, 12, 1)

Comment: i have try to write a code with replace  new DateTime(1998, 12, 1) but here and(&&) are not accepted ....